# while matching two values result did not print

Tags: php

when we are matching two values they are not giving us the result,however both values are same i.e. yes.whats the issue?

```
     $file_handle = fopen("data.txt", "rb");

     while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

      $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
        $parts = explode('\n', $line_of_text);
       array_push($r,$parts);
        }

       if($r[0][0]==$a[0])
           {
       echo "ride matched 123";
      }
         fclose($file_handle);
         ?>
```

Comment: For one, `explode('\n', $line_of_text);` will not split on newlines. Change it to use double-quotes: `explode("\n", $line_of_text);`. Or even better, use `PHP_EOL`, so your code is platform-independent: `explode(PHP_EOL, $line_of_text);`.

Comment: Splitting a variable called $line_of_text on newline makes no sense anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing each line of input onto the end of $r, but then always testing $r[0][0] so only the first line is ever tested.

Why not compare $parts[0] to $a[0] directly?